# Entity Framework error "Cannot use multiple context instances within a single query execution. Ensure the query uses a single context instance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

In my ASP.NET Core Web API, I had to use query tables from multiple databases in a server, but I am getting an error

> Cannot use multiple context instances within a single query execution. Ensure the query uses a single context instance

This is my query

```
using System.Linq;
using TMSAPI.api.Data;
using TMSAPI.api.Models.Domain;

namespace TMSAPI.api.Repositories
{
    public class Alarms : IAlarms
    {
        private readonly XAMRuntimeX4Context xAMRuntimeX4Context;
        private readonly XAMControlX4Context xAMControlX4Context;
        
        public Alarms(XAMRuntimeX4Context xAMRuntimeX4Context, XAMControlX4Context xAMControlX4Context)
        {
            this.xAMRuntimeX4Context = xAMRuntimeX4Context;
            this.xAMControlX4Context = xAMControlX4Context;
        }
        
        public IEnumerable<FinalAlarm> GetFinalAlarms()
        {
            var finalAlarm2 = xAMRuntimeX4Context.X4Journals
                                                 .Join(xAMControlX4Context.X4InstanceRemarks,
                                                       j => j.InstanceID, i => i.Instance_ID, (j, i) => new { j, i })
                                                 .Join(xAMControlX4Context.AutomationControlPropertyRemarks,
                                                       ppc => ppc.j.PropertyID, p => p.Property_ID, (ppc, p) => new { ppc.j, ppc.i, p })
                                                 .Join(xAMControlX4Context.X4AlarmConfigs,
                                                       ppc2 => new { k1 = ppc2.j.InstanceID, k2 = ppc2.j.PropertyID },
                                                       a => new { k1 = a.X4Instance_ID, k2 = a.X4Property_ID },
                                                       (ppc2, a) => new { ppc2.j, ppc2.i, ppc2.p, a })
                                                 .Join(xAMControlX4Context.X4AlarmGroups,
                                                       ppc3 => ppc3.a.X4AlarmGroup_ID, g => g.ID, (ppc3, g) => new { ppc3.j, ppc3.i, ppc3.p, ppc3.a, g })
                                                 .Where(ppc4 => ppc4.i.Language == "iv" && ppc4.p.Language == "iv")
                                                 .OrderBy(ppc4 => ppc4.j.OnTime)
                                                 .Select(x => new 
                                                              {
                                                                  x.j.ID,
                                                                  AlarmAppearTime = x.j.OnTime,
                                                                  AlarmDisappearTime = x.j.OffTime,
                                                                  AlarmAckTime = x.j.OnNoticeTime,
                                                                  AlarmCloseTime = x.j.OffNoticeTime,
                                                                  AssetID = x.j.InstanceID,
                                                                  Asset = x.i.RemarkPath,
                                                                  MessageID = x.j.PropertyID,
                                                                  AlarmMessage = x.p.Remark,
                                                                  PriorityID = x.a.X4AlarmGroup_ID,
                                                                  PriorityGroup = x.g.Name
                                                              });
            return (IEnumerable<FinalAlarm>)finalAlarm2.ToList();
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the same for you but, in Entity Framework Core I get this message if I didn't make a call to the database thread safe. Meaning I tried to use the same context to do two different things at the same time. I either fix it by creating a new context or creating Tasks with async to have other parts of the program keep going while one thread holds all those operations.

Comment: Thanks Byrd,could you please elaborate on solution,I have only this thread in my progrm

Comment: Well. It does look like that I haven't used this API so I'm not sure what they are doing with the stuff behind the scenes. But, also where are you calling GetFinalAlarms()?

Comment: GetFinalAarms() is called in a controller (Typical dotnet api pattern)

Comment: Maybe try creating a new instance of Alarms where the controller calls it? There's got to be a call somewhere that's holding up your context but still letting your UI thread keep going.

Comment: You could consider adding a View into your Control database pointing at the Runtime database table to get the Journals, then your Control DbContext can map a Journal entry to the view while the Runtume DbContext can map to a table.  Also, navigation properties for relationships between entities would make those relations a lot easier to work with.

Comment: @StevePy would you be able to help write this code using navigation properties.